# JQM fixed header with iOS transparent statur bar

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, iphone-web-app

What is the best way to change the JQM styles only for iOS with:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
```

in order to fix this [hidden header](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781449331085/full-screen/id2728123)? Is there a plugin for that?

Comment: What issue are you trying to fix? The link shows what the options do

Comment: @PhillPafford The third option shows the transparent status bar hides the header. My question is how to fix this in a bulletproof way.
I'd appreciate an answer from someone with good JQM experience.

Comment: I still don't understand the question, what do you want to fix? The options in the link show you the functionality. Sorry could you please go into detail?

Comment: @PhillPafford is there a way to push the header below a transparent status bar without messing too much with JQM layout?

Comment: You can't solve it just with CSS?
updated: have an idea for you, gimme a sec

Comment: @tsiokos so you want it to be transparent and the header not to slide up under the status bar?

Answer (score 1):

1st) you detect which os your client using:

```
osInfo.ios = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/); 
osInfo.android =  navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/);
osInfo.blackberry =  navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/);
```

2nd) you apply CSS so it will fix the position for iOs

```
if(osInfo.ios)
{
    //something here
}
```

P.S. hope I understood you right